# How to embed wxPython in wxWidgets (c++) app

Tags: python, visual-c++, wxpython, wxwidgets

I working on MSVC++ wxWidgets-3.0 application with embedded wxPython-3.0.

Though my system already had Python 2.7 & wxPython -3.0 installed i've done the following : (Since we need to have same build configuration for wxWidgets app , Python and wxPython)

- I have downloaded and built wxWidgets as DLL-Debug in 64 bit , then I
  ran sample minimal project with DLL-Debug mode (64 bit) sucessfully.

  I downloaded Python2.7 source and bulit it in Debug(64 bit) , then i
  copied debug dlls & libs  to python installation folder (\DLLs &
  \libs).

  I downloaded wxPython3.0 source and bulit it in DLL-Debug mode(64
  bit) , then i Copied debug dlls & libs  to python installed folder
  (\Lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx).

I got embedded.cpp from wxPython embedded samples and i copied the code from embedded.cpp to minimal.cpp of my wxWidgets samples minimal app.

project property setting:

c/c++:

```
  General    --  Additional include directories

                     C:\Python27\include

                     .\..\..\lib\vc_dll\mswud

                     .\..\..\include
```

Linker:

```
   General    --   Additional library directories

                         C:\Python27\libs

                         D:\Nuvsoft27\newpy\wxWidgets-3.0.0\lib\vc_dll


   Input         --   Additional dependncies

                          wxmsw30ud_core.lib
                                     .
                                     .
                                     .
                          Python27_d.lib
```

system environment variables.

```
 PATH   --    D:\Nuvsoft27\newpy\wxWidgets-3.0.0\lib\vc_dll

PYTHONPATH -- C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw
```

Issue:

it is failing in wxPyCoreAPI_IMPORT() function , its returning false.

Could you please help me out of this , am i doing anything wrong.

you can see **callstack** here:

```
wxPyCoreAPI_IMPORT() --> 

(wxPyCoreAPI*)PyCObject_Import("wx._core_", "_wxPyCoreAPI")  -->

PyImport_ImportModule(module_name) --> PyImport_Import(pname) -->

PyObject_CallFunction(import, "OOOOi", module_name, globals, globals, silly_list, 0, NULL);     --> 

call_function_tail(callable, args) --> PyObject_Call(callable, args, NULL) -->

PyCFunction_Call(PyObject *func, PyObject *arg, PyObject *kw) --> 

 builtin___import__(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds) -->

PyImport_ImportModuleLevel(char *name, PyObject *globals, PyObject *locals,  PyObject *fromlist, int level)  -->

 import_module_level(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level) -->

load_next(parent, level < 0 ? Py_None : parent, &name, buf,  &buflen); --> 

import_submodule(mod, p, buf);
```

In above function they are checking module if mod == Py_None they are returning NULL , it entering there & returning NULL.

Comment: Isn't it the same as your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524455/pyimport-importname-is-returning-null-which-will-be-called-by-wxpycoreapi-im)?

Comment: I think this is more specific: in this question, he is asking "why is the import returning false"?   The previous question was "how do I even go about this?"

Comment: @VZ Sorry for reapeating , i hope my previous question not clear.  could u please help out of this

Answer (score 0):

You probably also need to have c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw on the PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Thanks for replay but still i am having that issue , now you can see my updated data & callstack also to know exactly where it failing.